# Downloader doesnt get all the data

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, http

So i am trying to make a downloader based on http protocol. It works ok on small txt files, but if i try downloading something bigger, lets say a picture, it doesnt get all of the data.

```
void accel::getfile(int from, int to){
    //send GET message
    string msg = msg_get(fpath, true, from, to);
    int back = send(socketC, (char*)&msg[0], msg.size(), 0);

    //recv response
    int buffsize = 512;     //buffer size. should not be less than 512
    string buff(buffsize, 0);//, resp;  //buffer, response message
    fstream output(fname, ios::out, ios::trunc);    //file
    bool found = false;
    int dld = 0;

    do {
        //recv msg to buffer
        back = recv(socketC, (char*)&buff[0], buffsize, 0);
        dld += back;
        //buff.insert(back, "\0");
        //cout << buff.c_str();
        //is the writing of the body started?
        if (found){
            output.write(buff.c_str(), back);
            cout << ".";
        }
        //if not find where the body starts
        else {
            int point = buff.find("\r\n\r\n");
            if (point != -1){
                char *p = (char*)&buff[point+4];
                output.write(p, back-point-4);
                cout << ".";
                found = true;
            }
        }
    } while (back == buffsize);

    output.close();

    cout << "\nComplete\n";
    cout << dld << "bytes downloaded\n";
}
```

Requests:

```
string msg_head(string fpath, bool keep_alive){
    string msg;
    //
    msg = "HEAD ";
    msg += fpath;
    msg += " HTTP/1.0\r\n";

    if (keep_alive)
        msg += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    else
        msg += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    return msg;
}

string msg_get(string fpath, bool keep_alive, int from, int to){
    string msg;
    char number[10];

    msg = "GET ";
    msg += fpath;
    msg += " HTTP/1.0\r\n";

    msg += "Range: bytes=";
    sprintf(number, "%d", from);
    msg += number;
    msg += "-";
    sprintf(number, "%d", to);
    msg += number;
    msg += "\r\n";

    if (keep_alive)
        msg += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    else
        msg += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to assume that `recv` always returns the maximum amount of data (ie. that it waits for n bytes to appear). `recv` may return early if a smaller amount of data is currently available.

Instead, you should continue until either disconnection (when `recv` returns 0, or an error such as `WSAECONNRESET`) or an expected number of bytes (which you should have once the header is fully received)

Answer (score 1):

`recv` may not fill the whole buffer if there is not enough data available yet. You should detect the end of the message by one of the means specified in the [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).